# Unique strings in bash

Tags: array

I have an array

```
array=(src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c  qa/tests/ucode/chktest.pl  src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c src/profile/settings.txt  src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c  src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c src/ucode/pkgs/main_ch.c src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c)
```

I need to get unique files from that array

```
src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c  qa/tests/ucode/chktest.pl src/profile/settings.txt  src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c  src/ucode/pkgs/main_ch.c
```

Basically I need to delete duplicate strings from the array

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648410/how-can-i-get-unique-values-from-an-array-in-linux-bash

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```sh
#!/bin/bash

array=(src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c
qa/tests/ucode/chktest.pl
src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c
src/profile/settings.txt
src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c
src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c
src/ucode/pkgs/main_ch.c
src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c)

sorted_array=( $(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort | uniq) )

# dump the sorted array to check its contents
printf "%s\n" "${sorted_array[@]}"
```

output

```
qa/tests/ucode/chktest.pl
src/profile/settings.txt
src/ucode/pkgs/get_ch.c
src/ucode/pkgs/main_ch.c
src/ucode/pkgs/main_pf.c
```